# Editing android init.rc for third party daemon restart

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, daemon

I have a daemon written in C++ running on the background on android.

I want that daemon to restart upon crash or unexpected event without adding independent crash protection. What is the best way to do this ? I hope to edit init.rc.

Comment: Can you explain your question? Can you modify the image of your phone?   Are you creating a daemon to change Android's behavior? What's the purpose of the daemon?

Comment: I can modify the image. The daemon is simply running in support of a running application and communicating through a socket. The application is dependent on the daemon... therefore it needs to be always running. I am trying to accomplish this on Android 4.2 and 4.0.3. Also there is no JNI layer for the daemon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify in your *init.rc* file:

```
service <name> <pathname> [ <argument> ]
     critical
     <option>
     <option>
     ...
```

I think that in your case you should not specify options. However, [here](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/init/readme.txt) you can find the list of options. After editing init.rc run `make` command.

Comment: I should have said this is how i currently launch the daemon. However if I force a crash during operation it will not restart.

Comment: Try to add critical as an option.

Comment: critical is the way to go in jelly bean.